# Null checking for if then in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, null

I am checking two conditions which is following in C#:

```
 if (result.Data.Count > 0)
 {
     if(result.Data[0].AdditionalData != null)
      {
         // To Do
      }
  }
```

My confusion is there is any better way to check these in a single if condition?

I am trying to use Null-Condition operator, but did not work it. [Null-Conditional operator in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/csharp-the-new-and-improved-csharp-6-0)

Comment: `if(result.Data.FirstOrDefault()?.AdditionalData != null)`

Comment: Could `Data` be null as well? In that case you should add `Data?.`. You could use `Data?[0]` if `Data` might be null, but if it's not null but empty, you will get a index out of bounds exception, so in case that was what you tried and didn't work, that's right: it won't work.

Comment: Data is not null as I have check it now. But, Data might be empty and it's count would be then 0. @Andrew

Comment: @HansKilian solution is working fine.

Comment: It may work in your case (when looking for the first value), but if you want the second etc. then you need something different.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Your code is very easy to understand, while a null-coalescing operator may not be. You could also use a short-circuiting if:  `if (result.Data.Count > 0 && result.Data[0].AdditionalData != null)`

Comment: other solution is using `string.isNullorEmpty`  `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Data.FirstOrDefault()?.AdditionalData)`

Comment: Who voted for close? This is perfectly valid question, easily answerable, nothing opinion-based.

Comment: `Data.FirstOrDefault()?.AdditionalData == null` or `Data.ElementAtOrDefault()?.AdditionalData == null` are probably the closest options, see @SBFrancies [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70427176/475727)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One liner using `System.Linq`.

```
if (result.Data.FirstOrDefault()?.AdditionalDate != null)
{
 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like written also by @Hans Killian try to use the extensions already there for `IEnumerables`
In your case I think `.ElementAtOrDefault(0)` (or if you always want to use index 0 just use `.FirstOrDefault()`) is the best fit for you here.

```cs
if (result?.Data != null)
{
    /// Expecting 'AdditionalData' is `string`
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Data.ElementAtOrDefault(0)?.AdditionalData))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Null check working...");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AdditionalData is null or empty!");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No data!");
}
```

Full working example can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aV5zfQ)

Comment: `if(result.Data.Any())` un redundant, since you are using **OrDefault**: `ElementAtOrDefault(0)`

Comment: `if(result.Data.Any())` is redundant, since you are using **OrDefault** (`ElementAtOrDefault(0)`) which does the same check but more efficiently

Comment: @Liero Corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Null conditional can work along with `Any`, and short-circuiting the next check

```cs
if (result?.Data?.Any() && result.Data[0]?.AdditionalData != null)
{
    // to do
}
```

Explanation of each of the steps

`result?`

Is result not null?

`Data?`

if so, is Data not null?

`Any()`

if so, does Data have any items?

`Data[0]?`

if so, is the first item not null? (the reason I use index here is because you may want to check the nth item, so `FirstOrDefault` may be too restrictive)

`AdditionalData != null`

if so, is Additional data not null?

Of course, if any of these checks are unnecessary or superfluous you can remove the specific check from the chain (remove `?` in the case of null-conditional). Here the checks are all laid out clearly in one line so it's simple to modify the chain of logic.

Comment: Downvoting, because: assuming that the OP code worked, your code just adds 3 unnecessary null conditional operators and the two ifs are just rewritten using &&. This is little or no improvement.

Comment: @Liero OP never checked if Data is null so care to rethink that comment?

Comment: But the question was not about how to check Data or result for null. Maybe he is using nullable reference types so he actually knows it won't be null. It doesn't matter in context of this question.

Comment: Ok, I've removed the downvote

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to have clean and good code is to use FluentValidation. Please note the following code snippet:

```
public class RegisterValidator : AbstractValidator<RegisterDTO>
{
    public RegisterValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(a => a.PhoneNumber).NotNull().WithMessage(Utility.GetEnumTitlePersian(enmErrorMessage.InValidMobileNumber));
        RuleFor(a => a.PhoneNumber).NotEmpty().WithMessage(Utility.GetEnumTitlePersian(enmErrorMessage.InValidMobileNumber));
        RuleFor(a => a.PhoneNumber).MinimumLength(11).WithMessage(Utility.GetEnumTitlePersian(enmErrorMessage.InValidMobileNumber));
        RuleFor(a => a.PhoneNumber).MaximumLength(11).WithMessage(Utility.GetEnumTitlePersian(enmErrorMessage.InValidMobileNumber));
    }
}
```

The above code is an example of validating a model to check null, empty and etc. and this code must check validation in business logic:

```
var validator = new RegisterValidator();
var validatorResult = await validator.ValidateAsync(register);

if (!validatorResult.IsValid)
    return BadRequest("", validatorResult.Errors[0].ToString());
```

It is very simple to use and very clean. You can even perform multiple checks and get results through the error list

This link is the site address of [FluentValidation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/installation.html)

Comment: did you post your answer to invalid thread?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean!

Comment: Oh, sorry, at first I thought your answer in unrelated to this question.

Comment: No problem, I tried to provide a very comprehensive and complete solution

Comment: @MajidGholipour This answer has absolutely nothing to do with the question at all. Care to add an example to your answer dealing with the actual question?

Answer (score -1):

You can create extension method on IEnumerable and use it

```
    public static bool HasValue<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int index)
    {
        if (source == null)
            return false;

        return source.Count() > index && source.ElementAt(index) != null;
    }

// usage
if(result.Data.HasValue(0))
{
}
```

Comment: May be this should work but this would be a long effort for my purpose.

Comment: This would iterare the source twice. Completely unnecessary.